# Jquery Mobile alternative icons by default?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I set jquery mobile to use the alternative icons(black) by default?

Using markup language you can do it using [ui-alt-icon](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.5/icons/#&ui-state=dialog):

```
<a href="index.html" class="ui-alt-icon ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left">Alt icon</a>
<a href="index.html" class="ui-alt-icon ui-btn ui-shadow ui-corner-all ui-btn-b ui-icon-delete ui-btn-icon-left">Alt icon</a>
```

Is it possible to do this for all the buttons without adding ui-alt-icon individually to each icon? I'm looking for a JavaScript setting that overrides this globally.

Answer (score 8):

The global setting is to run this jquery on the web page, that is loading JQuery mobile script:

```
$('body').addClass('ui-alt-icon');
```

if you want only a section to have the alternate Icons then the section or parent of the element block you want affected, then run for all **ui-button's**:

```
$('.ui-btn').addClass('ui-alt-icon');
```

or for an element with the id **ElementID**:

```
$('#ElementID').addClass('ui-alt-icon');
```

Obviously all the jquery commands need to be in script tags after the DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 5):

Add `ui-alt-icon` class to the `<body>` tag.

Answer (score 0):

The way of javascript might lead to inconsistency between buttons as jquery mobile performs a lot of dynamic DOM updates.

Most of the button styling is drawn from jquery mobile sprite like [here](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.1/css/themes/default/images/icons-18-white.png). A neat way to accomplish this is to just switch your sprites.